# random integers and receiving them and saving them

Tags: python

So I'm quite new to Python and I've been making a dice roll for a lesson in class and I'm really stuck on it. My code works very well except for the point where the dice roll happens. If you roll a 6 then it should print that I win. But it prints that I lost. I have no idea why this is happening and any help would be appreciated. It's designed to ask you your name, give you a username and then ask if you want to play. But everything goes wrong at the end where you're given the number. Like I say I'd appreciate the test

```
from random import randint

print ("Hello, whats is your first name?")
first_name = input()
print ("What is your second name?")
second_name = input()
username = first_name[0] + first_name[1] + second_name[0] + second_name[1]
print (username + ", I want to play a game. Do you accept?")
game = input()
if game == ("yes") or ("Yes") or :
print ("Great, let's play. I'm going to roll a dice, if it lands on a 6, you win. If")
print ("not, you lose.")
dice_roll = print (randint(1,6))
if dice_roll == 6:
    print ("Congrats, you win.")
elif dice_roll != 6:
    print ("Sorry. You lose.")
elif game == ("no") or ("No"):
    print ("Ok, Bye.")
else:
    print ("Ok, Bye.")
```

Comment: Your main question has been answered, but I wanted to point out something else you may not be aware of.  The line "username = first_name[0] + first_name[1] + second_name[0] + second_name[1]" will cause your program to abort with an "index out of range" error if someone just hits return at the name prompts, or enters less than 2 characters for a name.  You must check that the length is valid before attempting to access it via an index variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you doing the following

```
dice_roll = print (randint(1,6))
```

This would print to console and return none. so, dice_roll is always None. SO, change it to the following

```
dice_roll = randint(1,6)
```

To print it, just print it on a separate line.

Also, one more problem is the following line

```
if game == ("yes") or ("Yes") or :
```

you cannot do that. you have to mention some thing after "or". So, change it to the following

```
if game == "yes" or game == "Yes" :
```

Comment: and do the print statement on a separate line if you need

Answer (score 1):

You`ll need to change this line:

```
dice_roll = print (randint(1,6))
```

because you assign dice_roll parameter to print statement, if you use:

```
dice_roll = (randint(1,6))
print(dice_roll)
```

everything should be OK.

Also, you can slim your code by changing (and also eleminating two "or" statements):

```
if game == ("yes") or ("Yes") or :
```

to:

```
if game.lower() == "yes":
```

this will handle great letter exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Change the rolling part like to print the result, not assigning the print to a variable -but the value itself:

```
dice_roll = randint(1,6)
print(dice_roll)
if dice_roll == 6:
    print ("Congrats, you win.")
elif dice_roll != 6:
    print ("Sorry. You lose.")
elif game == ("no") or ("No"):
    print ("Ok, Bye.")
else:
    print ("Ok, Bye.")
```